# CSS Image Grid with hover effect to each image

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay, css-grid

I am trying to create a simple image grid and I would like to add hover effects to each image. I would like the effect to be a transition to a different image. so far I have the image grid worked out properly but when it comes to adding a hover effect its either effecting my entire column by making images disappear or the image I am using for the transition covers the entire grid. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code that I've been working with so far

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  -ms-flex: 20%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">
 
</div>

<!-- Photo Grid -->


<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1BiM6pgdVUC8H7A-pO9YMD74jwcvh8uKw" style="width:100%">

    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1TBfdXETiX00bNkSxTkeePnAJb_TE8KMz" style="width:100%">
   
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1jN0LLKTg7H1j0PQ1estEOSgbxN8IaUhX" style="width:100%">
   
  </div>
 
 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1XI0X_JIsOrpR6AjKxFR2MHdu7KqmbKDf" style="width:100%">
   
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1iSMUDDa3_NQF3FaDw_L0J3b6EypDUlRn" style="width:100%">
   
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1HUhl-gkKjZO2APycCl0Z5Bhm_EWcNoWo" style="width:100%">
  </div>
 
 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1-g11eGfBGMtng5eW7MSBTmVjGEc7X3KT" style="width:100%">
   
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1GIssifV2o9YbcM-b_LDe0AwkBqb7WHkE" style="width:100%">
   
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1vdVGVohUrDrkjoOHAi2QFwLDFypdkRR8" style="width:100%">
  </div>
 
 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1veQWJj6J3_NW48y4-_cTr2PeO9mhcktm" style="width:100%">
   
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1OFAR6Dh3vMJ7DQnkm4TVky3iBDada5iY" style="width:100%">
   
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1XRwvxsxI8N32HT-XETAxt82j6EA30jF2" style="width:100%">
  </div>
 
 
   <div class="column">
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1J1ctFtgHtd0G5gddcZzsSuM-eUpiWsOQ" style="width:100%">
   
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1-oD6Rc5q5Xzq6Qt-FJdfh7pMZo165m3Z" style="width:100%">
   
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1I-zlWhtolgyH_Ewr3F239maUizVjtJRM" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/KJ618/pen/ZEpmLPE

Comment: sent you a link to what im working with so far

Comment: @user15003353 can you add more detail or example of the hover transition that you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for the help! It's similar to this!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_fade

Comment: But instead of fading to text, another image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS `transition` property will help you to achieve this.
You can also use CSS `grid` for creating the Grid Layout

**Checkout the sample code.**

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(220px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cell {
  width: auto;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.cell .content:last-child:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
.content>img{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1BiM6pgdVUC8H7A-pO9YMD74jwcvh8uKw" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1TBfdXETiX00bNkSxTkeePnAJb_TE8KMz" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1jN0LLKTg7H1j0PQ1estEOSgbxN8IaUhX" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1XI0X_JIsOrpR6AjKxFR2MHdu7KqmbKDf" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1iSMUDDa3_NQF3FaDw_L0J3b6EypDUlRn" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1HUhl-gkKjZO2APycCl0Z5Bhm_EWcNoWo" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1-g11eGfBGMtng5eW7MSBTmVjGEc7X3KT" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1GIssifV2o9YbcM-b_LDe0AwkBqb7WHkE" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1BiM6pgdVUC8H7A-pO9YMD74jwcvh8uKw" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1TBfdXETiX00bNkSxTkeePnAJb_TE8KMz" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1jN0LLKTg7H1j0PQ1estEOSgbxN8IaUhX" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1XI0X_JIsOrpR6AjKxFR2MHdu7KqmbKDf" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1iSMUDDa3_NQF3FaDw_L0J3b6EypDUlRn" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1HUhl-gkKjZO2APycCl0Z5Bhm_EWcNoWo" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1-g11eGfBGMtng5eW7MSBTmVjGEc7X3KT" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1GIssifV2o9YbcM-b_LDe0AwkBqb7WHkE" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ill test it out. Thank you for the response! I just want to make sure this is responsive as Im using this for a shopify site. I want it to be 5 by 3 on a desktop and work well on a phone.

Comment: I haven't written the code for responsiveness, please try it if it is not responsive please set the grid-template-columns and grid template-rows based on screen size

Comment: I tried it and you are correct. Ill see how I can edit it to be responsive but other than that it works well for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: do you think you can help with the responsive design with this?

Comment: It's Actually simple you can make the grid responsive by setting  `grid-template-columns` to `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(220px, 1fr))` it will automatically resize your grid, but if you need more control you can use @media queries. For more info on repeat see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat()

Comment: i have updated the example, just go through it, here i have set the image width to 100%, you can alter it to any width , i set it because you wont be able to see any change since your images are exactly 220px.